# ArcGIS Javascript Click Returning Invalid Coordinates

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am using ArcGIS Javascript SDK 3.17 to display some points on a map, and when the user selects the point it takes them to Google Maps driving directions.  The points are displaying in the correct location but when I click the graphic it sends some weird coordinates to Google Maps such as -8622416.7705,4523370.1646

Here is my code for the click event:

```
map.on("click", function (evt) {
   var lat = evt.mapPoint.x.toString();
   var lng = evt.mapPoint.y.toString();
   window.location = "comgooglemaps://?daddr=" + lat + "," + lng + "&directionsmode=driving";
});
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: Because the map is in 3857, web Mercator. You'll need to convert them to lat lon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @mkennedy said in her comment, you need to convert to a GCS, particularly WGS 1984 if you want lat/long.  You can accomplish this using the [webMercatorUtils](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/esri.geometry.webmercatorutils-amd.html):

```
// need to import 'esri/geometry/webMercatorUtils' and 'esri/SpatialRefeference'
var wgs84 = new SpatialReference({wkid: 4326});

// convert map coordinates to WGS 84
map.on("click", function (evt) {
  if (webMercatorUtils.canProject(evt.mapPoint, wgs84){
    var wgsPt = webMercatorUtils.project(evt.mapPoint, wgs84);
    window.location = "comgooglemaps://?daddr=" + wgsPt.y + "," + wgsPt.x + "&directionsmode=driving";
  }
});
```